# Exercise on application of global existance and uniqueness of solution theorem for an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to prove that for the equation:

$$y'(x)=1+\sin^2(y(x))$$

I started notice that $y'(x)$ is a limited, continuos and $C^{\infty}$ function defined on $R^{2}$. Due to it's limitation I can intuitively say that it's a Lipschitz continuous function, so there exist both global and local solutions.

Could someone help me to say this stuff in a more advanced math language, proving the Lipschitz conditions? Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(t,y)=1+\sin^2 y$ is differentiable and thus locally Lipschitz, which provides uniqueness.

As $f$ and thus $y'$ is bounded, you get that $y$ is bounded over any finite interval, which proves that any solution can be extended without bound, i.e., any maximal solution has all of $\Bbb R$ as domain.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. So, it's the differentiability of a function sufficient to say that a function is locally Lipschitz? Thank you. :).

Comment: Yes, as the maximum of the derivative is a Lipschitz constant by the mean value theorem resp. mean value inequality.

Comment: Thank you for yout fast reply! Let me give a final example: if I have $y'=\frac{y^{3}}{1+x^{2}}$. It's clear that the domain is the whole R and is a continuous derivable function. Is this funcion locally Lipschitz? I would say yes (for some small subset of R) but not globally Lipschitz beacuse of the non limitation of $y'$ respect to $y$. Am I right? Thank you :).

Comment: Yes, that is correct, $y\mapsto y^3$ is only Lipschitz continuous on bounded intervals.

Comment: Thank you, your help has been very useful for me to understand this point. :)